# bootstrap col-xs not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code for Employer page. The bootstrap `col-xs` is not working. While I reduce the size of browser to `xs` width the text boxes are not changing there size. The box is actually going out of panel limits.

Can somebody help me with a solution?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    
    <head>
    
    <title> Employer Registration Page </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="empreg1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="try2.js"></script>
    <style type ="text/css">
      
      sup{
      color:red;
      }
      .paddi{
      padding:10px;
      }
      
      input[type="text"] {
        width: 300px;
    }
    input[type="password"]{
    width:300px;
    }
      
      #errorBox{
      color:red;
      }
      .mar{
      margin-top:100px;
      }
      </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class= "col-xs-offset-6 col-xs-6 paddi">
    <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-lg"><strong>Already a member. Please Sign In</strong></button>
    </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mar">
      
    <form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="#">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <h3>
    New Client Registration
    </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="errorBox"></div>
    <div class="page-header paddi">
    <h4>
    Create your Account Details
    </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="email">
    <sup>*</sup>Email ID: 
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name= "eid" id="eid" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="pwd">
    <sup>*</sup>Create a Password for your account: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cpwd">
    
    <sup>*</sup>Confirm Password: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="password" name="cpwd" id="cpwd" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cname">
    <sup>*</sup>Company Name: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name="cname" id="cname"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="ctype">
    <sup>*</sup>Company Type:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name= "ctype" class="rdo"/>Company </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="ctype" class="rdo" /> Consultant </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name ="ctype" class="rdo" /> Recruiter </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="itype">
    <sup>*</sup>Industry Type:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <select id="itype">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="Agri">Agri</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="lcn">
    Location: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
     <input type="text" name="lcn" id="lcn" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cntry">
    <sup>*</sup>Country: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <select id="cntry">
    
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cnum">
    <sup>*</sup>Contact Number:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name="cnum" id="cnum"/>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cpnm">
    <sup>*</sup>Contact Person Name:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name="cpnm" id="cpnm" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
    
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="acd"> <sup>*</sup>About Company:
    </label>
    
    <div class="col-xs-7">
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="acd"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="control-group">
            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="controls col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">
             <button class="btn btn-success" id="reg">Register</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Please add code online, jsbin example

Comment: Not related to the problem But you need to reference your jquery library before any other jquery dependent plugin file.

Comment: @Rajshekar Reddy he had one, before <html> section............. and second one after bootstrap js

Answer (score 1):

You can make "sign-in" button more narrow, because its content can't wrap.
Look at my solution:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    
    <head>
    
    <title> Employer Registration Page </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="empreg1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="try2.js"></script>
    <style type ="text/css">
      
      sup{
      color:red;
      }
      .paddi{
      padding:10px;
      }
      
      input[type="text"] {
        width: 300px;
    }
    input[type="password"]{
    width:300px;
    }
      
      #errorBox{
      color:red;
      }
      .mar{
      margin-top:100px;
      }
      </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    <div class= "col-xs-offset-6 col-xs-6 paddi">
    Already a member? Please <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-lg"><strong>Sign In</strong></button>
    </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mar">
      
    <form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="#">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <h3>
    New Client Registration
    </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="errorBox"></div>
    <div class="page-header paddi">
    <h4>
    Create your Account Details
    </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="email">
    <sup>*</sup>Email ID: 
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name= "eid" id="eid" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="pwd">
    <sup>*</sup>Create a Password for your account: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cpwd">
    
    <sup>*</sup>Confirm Password: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="password" name="cpwd" id="cpwd" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cname">
    <sup>*</sup>Company Name: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name="cname" id="cname"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="ctype">
    <sup>*</sup>Company Type:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name= "ctype" class="rdo"/>Company </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="ctype" class="rdo" /> Consultant </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name ="ctype" class="rdo" /> Recruiter </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="itype">
    <sup>*</sup>Industry Type:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <select id="itype">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="Agri">Agri</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="lcn">
    Location: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
     <input type="text" name="lcn" id="lcn" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cntry">
    <sup>*</sup>Country: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <select id="cntry">
    
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cnum">
    <sup>*</sup>Contact Number:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name="cnum" id="cnum"/>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cpnm">
    <sup>*</sup>Contact Person Name:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name="cpnm" id="cpnm" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
    
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="acd"> <sup>*</sup>About Company:
    </label>
    
    <div class="col-xs-7">
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="acd"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="control-group">
            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="controls col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">
             <button class="btn btn-success" id="reg">Register</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is another solution, where cell defined as col-xs-12  added bootstrap class `text-right` to alighn its content to the right

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    
    <head>
    
    <title> Employer Registration Page </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="empreg1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="try2.js"></script>
    <style type ="text/css">
      
      sup{
      color:red;
      }
      .paddi{
      padding:10px;
      }
      
      input[type="text"] {
        width: 300px;
    }
    input[type="password"]{
    width:300px;
    }
      
      #errorBox{
      color:red;
      }
      .mar{
      margin-top:100px;
      }
      </style>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    <div class= "col-xs-12 paddi text-right">
    <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-lg"><strong>Already a member. Please Sign In</strong></button>
    </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mar">
      
    <form  class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="#">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
      <h3>
    New Client Registration
    </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div id="errorBox"></div>
    <div class="page-header paddi">
    <h4>
    Create your Account Details
    </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="email">
    <sup>*</sup>Email ID: 
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name= "eid" id="eid" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="pwd">
    <sup>*</sup>Create a Password for your account: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cpwd">
    
    <sup>*</sup>Confirm Password: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="password" name="cpwd" id="cpwd" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cname">
    <sup>*</sup>Company Name: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name="cname" id="cname"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="ctype">
    <sup>*</sup>Company Type:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name= "ctype" class="rdo"/>Company </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="ctype" class="rdo" /> Consultant </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name ="ctype" class="rdo" /> Recruiter </label>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="itype">
    <sup>*</sup>Industry Type:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <select id="itype">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="Agri">Agri</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="lcn">
    Location: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
     <input type="text" name="lcn" id="lcn" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cntry">
    <sup>*</sup>Country: </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <select id="cntry">
    
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cnum">
    <sup>*</sup>Contact Number:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name="cnum" id="cnum"/>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="cpnm">
    <sup>*</sup>Contact Person Name:
    </label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
    <input type="text" name="cpnm" id="cpnm" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
    
    <label class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right" for="acd"> <sup>*</sup>About Company:
    </label>
    
    <div class="col-xs-7">
     <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="acd"></textarea>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="control-group">
            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="controls col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-2">
             <button class="btn btn-success" id="reg">Register</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can not use width PX for any element with responsive layout. Or you have to use media tag, to define it for all devices. Simpliest solution is to remove your inputs width:

```
 input[type="text"] {
    width: 300px;
}
```

and same for password. Use width 100% or define media max/min width sizes. Example:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 300px;
}
@media (max-width:500px){
    input[type="text"] {
        width: 150px;
    }
}
```

With this code, on devices smaller than 500px, you will have input length equal 150px. Below you have bootstrap defaults sizes for all devices:

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

}



/*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

}

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

}
```